# How to change the activity history

Tags: android, android-activity

There are six activities A,B,C,D,E and F. Each of them have been opened in the following order: A,B,C,D,E,F. When I now go from activity F to activity B, I would like to have a subsequent press on the back button open activity A. How can this outcome be achieved?

Comment: How about finishing activity C by calling finish() method just before you start activity D. And pressing back in activity B will take you to activity A as it is just above it.

Comment: AngadSingh's suggestion will work. But we need more information on what you want to happen between activity B to activity F. For example ,if you want to go back to activity C when you press the back button when activity D is open then calling `finish` is not the solution. Please edit your Question to explain the activity flow more completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with Intent flags.

When you start Activity B from Activity F you use a flag in your intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, B.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will cause all of the intermediate activities to be finished (C, D and F), and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will make sure that you return to the same instance of Activity B.

If you want for activity B to be finished and a new instance to be created, remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Also you can change activity B `launchMode` instead of using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) are some more info on the matter